# display anchor tag and arrow(using border) in same line using `display:inline block`

Tags: html, css

This the sample html  to display text and arrow(using border) in same line.

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.tomsAccLeftPaneArrow {
  position: relative;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #979492;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tomsTabs tomsSideNav">
  <li id="track_tab">
    <div class="wrap">
      <a href="#track" aria-label="Show track ">TOP QUESTIONS
         <div class="tomsAccLeftPaneArrow">&nbsp;</div></a>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How to display anchor tag and arrow ("tomsAccLeftPaneArrow") in the same line using `display:inline block`? 
Can anyone give me a solution please.
[image]

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of what you're hoping to achieve please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pseudo object and absolute position the arrow next to the anchor point.

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
a {
  position: relative;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #979492;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tomsTabs tomsSideNav">
  <li id="track_tab">
    <div class="wrap">
      <a href="#track" aria-label="Show track ">TOP QUESTIONS</a>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See in action: https://jsfiddle.net/wfwo6mb2/

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the solution. Is it possible to do this without using after and using .tomsAccLeftPaneArrow  dom

Comment: When the browser size decreases the arrow coming down. I need to have the arrow always at top, only the text get shrink. How to do this?

Comment: could you please suggest me a solution

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot. Not sure what you're trying to achieve. Thanks

Comment: Hi carlosp120 I have attached the screenshot please verify it. When the browser shrinks the arrow always should be at top, without using top property.

Comment: @Mahi - Take a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/wfwo6mb2/2/ -- I added a max-width to test what happens when the text has to go to the next line, feel free to remove that line, but arrow is now at the top. Copy/paste updated css.

Comment: The thing is i should not allowed to use these 3( position, top and right)

Comment: What do you mean you're not allowed? The parent element is a relative element, so it should just go to the top of the parent, not the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="wrap">
    <a href="#track" aria-label="Show track" style="display: inline-flex;text-decoration:none"><span>TOP QUESTIONS</span><span style="margin: 2px;font-size: 24px;">&#707;</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the class `'wrap'` to that anchor tag and the arrow `div` tag.

e.g.
Change this:

```
<div class="wrap">
        <a href="#track" aria-label="Show track ">TOP QUESTIONS
        <div class="tomsAccLeftPaneArrow">&nbsp;</div></a>
    </div>
```

To This:

```
<div>
      <a href="#track" aria-label="Show track" class="wrap">TOP QUESTIONS</a> 
      <div class="tomsAccLeftPaneArrow wrap">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First place your text `TOP QUESTIONS` in a div and add

```
float:left;
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
```

in the css so that the next div will be next to it. Then for the next div add

```
left:100%
margin-top:5px;
```

so that the arrow will be placed at the end of the first div and additional margin on top will align the arrow in the middle of the text.

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.tomsAccLeftPaneArrow {
  position: relative;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #979492;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  left:100%;
  margin-top:5px;
}

.ques{
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tomsTabs tomsSideNav">
  <li id="track_tab">
    <div class="wrap">
      <a href="#track" aria-label="Show track ">
        <div class="ques">TOP QUESTIONS</div>
        <div class="tomsAccLeftPaneArrow"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:after` instead of using a separate element for the arrow like this:

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.arrow-link::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: ' ';
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-top: 2px solid #999;
  border-right: 2px solid #999;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="tomsTabs tomsSideNav">
  <li id="track_tab">
    <div class="wrap">
      <a href="#track" aria-label="Show track ">
        <div class="arrow-link">TOP QUESTIONS</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

please check this fiddle, your ans is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/krdpn7zc/1/

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.tomsAccLeftPaneArrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #979492;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  right: -12px;
  top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tomsTabs tomsSideNav">
  <li id="track_tab">
    <div class="wrap">
      <a href="#track" aria-label="Show track ">TOP QUESTIONS
                <div class="tomsAccLeftPaneArrow">&nbsp;</div></a>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```